# How to use UNION while inserting in a table using SELECT clause from many tables in SQL Server 2000

Tags: sql-server, select, insert, union

I am using SQL Server 2000. I have multiple criterias which i have to use to extract different sets of records from mumtiple table in another  table. I am using

```
INSERT INTO T1(A,B)
(SELECT E,R FROM T2)
UNION
(SELECT Z,X FROM T3)
```

Query analyzer is throwing error that while using `UNION`, you should use `ORDER BY` clause with `SELECT`. Even after doing that i m not able to union two different queries which are returing same columns in their select clause.

What is the right way to insert using `SELECTS` with `UNIONS` and `ORDER BY`.

Comment: Just get rid of the parentheses and the query you posted should work in principle assuming it returns a union compatible result (though it would do 2 cartesian joins which probably isn't the desired semantics). And of course the result would need to be compatible with the `insert` statement which could only be the case if all 4 tables involved only had 1 column. Frankly the example code you posted seems quite nonsensical. Can you explain why/where you are using `order by` here as that doesn't even feature anywhere in it?

Comment: it surprised me as well. For simple inserts like CREATE TABLE BB(NAME VARCHAR(200)) INSERT INTO BB SELECT NAME FROM FS77..S_ORG_EXT WHERE NAME LIKE '%Hos%' UNION SELECT NAME FROM FS77..S_ORG_EXT WHERE NAME LIKE '%Com%'   it works fine, but for the complex one i m using with different SQLs retruning same columns in select and different WHERE clauses using UNION, IT THrows an error saying  Server: Msg 104, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if the statement contains a UNION operator.

Comment: Before using UNION, using individual INSERT Using SELECT, i am using some criteria in join where i am using ORDER BY COL_NAME without using COL_NAME in SELECT on a join, with UNION, it is creating problem which i m not able to understand.

Comment: I have used couple of joins like this LEFT OUTER JOIN FS77..S_CONTACT_XM REQXM ON REQXM.PAR_ROW_ID = REQ.ROW_ID AND REQXM.TYPE = 'Contact Program' AND REQXM.ATTRIB_03 = 'Orencia Reimb Support Services' AND REQXM.ROW_ID = (SELECT TOP 1 ROW_ID FROM FS77..S_CONTACT_XM WHERE PAR_ROW_ID = REQ.ROW_ID AND 
TYPE = 'Contact Program' ORDER BY CREATED DESC)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The pseudo is too cryptic (reduced?)
It is very unlikely to get 2 columns per cross join of 2 tables in each of the union components

```
INSERT INTO T1(A,B)
(SELECT * FROM E,R)
UNION
(SELECT * FROM Z,X)
```

Note: If you have ANY order by clause at all, it *must* be at the end of the union

```
INSERT T1(A,B)
SELECT P,Q FROM E,R
UNION
SELECT R,S FROM Z,X
```

*@updated based on error text "Server: Msg 104, Level 15, State 1, Line 1 ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if the statement contains a UNION operator"*

This occurs when you have a union that attempts to perform ORDER BY on a column that does not appear in the result.  Consider a normal ORDER BY involving non-selected columns

```
select top 10 name from syscolumns order by xtype
```

The rows are consistent and the query can be satisfied.  However, if you did

```
select top 10 name from syscolumns where xtype > 50
union all
select top 10 name from syscolumns where xtype < 50
order by xtype
```

EVEN IF xtype exists in both parts of the UNION, but the time it gets presented to ORDER BY (which works at the END over the entire result set), the column is not there.  You would have to rewrite it (if you didn't want to show `xtype`) as

```
select name from (
    select top 10 name, xtype from syscolumns where xtype > 50
    union all
    select top 10 name, xtype from syscolumns where xtype < 50
) x
order by xtype
```

Hope that helps

Comment: I have put couple of joins like this which are not near UNION, as they are on joins, LEFT OUTER JOIN FS77..S_CONTACT_XM REQXM ON REQXM.PAR_ROW_ID = REQ.ROW_ID AND REQXM.TYPE = 'Contact Program' AND REQXM.ATTRIB_03 = 'Orencia Reimb Support Services' AND REQXM.ROW_ID = (SELECT TOP 1 ROW_ID FROM FS77..S_CONTACT_XM WHERE PAR_ROW_ID = REQ.ROW_ID AND TYPE = 'Contact Program' ORDER BY CREATED DESC) can it create a problem.. individual queries are working fine. should these be after WHERE clause.

Comment: That should probably be INSERT INTO T1(A,B)
SELECT * FROM E,R
UNION
(SELECT * FROM Z,X)